# How to gather code into one variable

Tags: php

I need to be able to get all of this information (as text) into the variable $all so that I can use it later in my script. But when I echo $all later on it doesn't work. And don't anyone say anything about the use of font tags, I'm as depressed about it as you are.

```
   $all = <<< STOPTHISCRAZYTHING
    echo "<br><br><textarea rows=\"30\" cols = \"100\">";
    echo "<div align=\"center\"><font size=\"7\">I Have</font></div>";
    foreach($same as $match)
        {
        echo "<img src=\"" . $match . "\">";
        }
    echo "<div align=\"center\"><font size=\"7\">I Need</font></div>";
    foreach($different as $diff)
        {
        if(!in_array($diff, $reject))
        {
        echo "<img src=\"" . $diff . "\">";
        }
        }
    echo "<div align=\"center\"><font size=\"7\">I Am Unable To Obtain</font></div>";
    foreach($retired_different as $unabletoget)
        {
        echo "<img src=\"" . $unabletoget . "\">";
        }
    echo "</textarea>";
STOPTHISCRAZYTHING;
```

Comment: doesn't work, as in nothing is printed? or is something partially printed?

Comment: It's all messed up, though it's printed.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is of no use in diagnosing the problem.  Please specify in what way it doesn't work.

Comment: It says echo " then a small textarea with the code in it. Not the text I want, but the code. Then there is an "; immediately after the textarea.

Comment: what you really want is a function, that you can call later.  echo-ing php code will not execute the code

Comment: this. Unless you are trying to dynamically generate code (I really, really don't think you are) then you shouldn't be storing it as a string. Use Madbreak's response below or deltree's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php):

```
ob_start(); // Start capturing the script's output

echo "<br><br><textarea rows=\"30\" cols = \"100\">";
echo "<div align=\"center\"><font size=\"7\">I Have</font></div>";
foreach($same as $match)
    {
    echo "<img src=\"" . $match . "\">";
    }
echo "<div align=\"center\"><font size=\"7\">I Need</font></div>";
foreach($different as $diff)
    {
    if(!in_array($diff, $reject))
    {
    echo "<img src=\"" . $diff . "\">";
    }
    }
echo "<div align=\"center\"><font size=\"7\">I Am Unable To Obtain</font></div>";
foreach($retired_different as $unabletoget)
    {
    echo "<img src=\"" . $unabletoget . "\">";
    }
echo "</textarea>";

$all = ob_get_flush(); // Stop capturing output, and store the output 
// that was captured up until now into the variable $all
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't embed looping constructs in heredoc syntax.  You need to handle your foreach loops outside of the:

```
$all = STOPTHISCRAZYTHING
    ...
STOPTHISCRAZYTHING;
```

**EDIT:**

Ditto on the 'echo' statements.  You can use variables in your heredoc assignment, but you can think of it as the whole block being the right side of a string assignment.  Not a block in which you execute PHP commands.

**EDIT 2:**

Here's a valid example, using your example (part of it)

```
    $all = <<< STOPTHISCRAZYTHING
        <br><br><textarea rows="30" cols ="100">
        <div align="center"><font size="7">I Have</font></div>
STOPTHISCRAZYTHING;
```

...note how you just enter the text you need, you don't have to echo, nor do you have to escape quotes.

docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Cheers

Comment: So how would I make this work by putting everything in one variable then?

Comment: Prior to your heredoc chunk, process each `foreach` loop, but instead of echoing your text, append it to a string variable, e.g. `$images1` for the first `foreach` loop, `$images2` for the 2nd, etc.  Then inside your heredoc chunk, just place that variable where you want that text to appear in the output.  PHP will expand it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean with `It's all messed up, though it's printed.` but it seems to me it gets printed just fine but the browser is showing you the rendered version: Just check the source code.

What you need to do if you want to see it as real text is:

- wrap it in `<pre>` tags to preserve the line-breaks (or use `nl2br()` on the string before echoing it)
- use `htmlspecialchars()` on the variable before you echo it so that the `<` etc. symbols get converted to html entities.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to do, you would be able to accomplish by using ob_start() and friends. heredoc (<<<) is simply for creating large string variables without using quotes. you cannot put code and all that stuff inside of a heredoc string.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

ob_start() can let you buffer everything you print. you can then use the other ob functions to get that buffered output and place it into a variable or whatever you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You've got some interesting bracketing going on there....

Do you need to use `Heredoc`? 
Why not just add it all into a variable using the "." operator to concatenate them. Also to simplify things you can use a mixture of single and double quotes:

> ```
> $all = "<br><br><textarea rows='30' cols = '100'>";
> $all = $all . "<div align='center'><font size='7'>I Have</font></div>";
> foreach($same as $match)
> {
>     $all = $all . "<img src='" . $match . "'>";
> }
> $all = $all . "<div align='center'><font size='7'>I Need</font></div>";
> foreach($different as $diff)
> {
>     if(!in_array($diff, $reject))
> {
> $all = $all . "<img src='" . $diff . "'>";
> $all = $all . "<div align='center'><font size='7'>I Am Unable To Obtain</font></div>";
> foreach($retired_different as $unabletoget)
> {
>     $all = $all . "<img src='" . $unabletoget . "'>";
> }
> $all = $all . "</textarea>";
> ```

Now when you echo the $all variable you will get the full output you desire

> ```
> echo $all;
> ```

Answer (score -1):

**Solution A :**

```
<?php
   $all = <<< STOPTHISCRAZYTHING
    echo "&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;textarea rows=\"30\" cols = \"100\"&gt;";
    echo "&lt;div align=\"center\"&gt;&lt;font size=\"7\"&gt;I Have&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;";
    foreach($same as $match)
        {
        echo "&lt;img src=\"" . $match . "\"&gt;";
        }
    echo "&lt;div align=\"center\"&gt;&lt;font size=\"7\"&gt;I Need&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;";
    foreach($different as $diff)
        {
        if(!in_array($diff, $reject))
        {
        echo "&lt;img src=\"" . $diff . "\"&gt;";
        }
        }
    echo "&lt;div align=\"center\"&gt;&lt;font size=\"7\"&gt;I Am Unable To Obtain&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/div&gt;";
    foreach($retired_different as $unabletoget)
        {
        echo "&lt;img src=\"" . $unabletoget . "\"&gt;";
        }
    echo "&lt;/textarea&gt;";
STOPTHISCRAZYTHING;

echo $all;

?>
```

**Solution B *(use `htmlentities`)*:**

```
<?php
   $all = <<< STOPTHISCRAZYTHING
    echo "<br><br><textarea rows=\"30\" cols = \"100\">";
    echo "<div align=\"center\"><font size=\"7\">I Have</font></div>";
    foreach($same as $match)
        {
        echo "<img src=\"" . $match . "\">";
        }
    echo "<div align=\"center\"><font size=\"7\">I Need</font></div>";
    foreach($different as $diff)
        {
        if(!in_array($diff, $reject))
        {
        echo "<img src=\"" . $diff . "\">";
        }
        }
    echo "<div align=\"center\"><font size=\"7\">I Am Unable To Obtain</font></div>";
    foreach($retired_different as $unabletoget)
        {
        echo "<img src=\"" . $unabletoget . "\">";
        }
    echo "</textarea>";
STOPTHISCRAZYTHING;

echo htmlentities($all);

?>
```

**Solution C *(wrap it in `<pre>`...`</pre>` tags)*:**

```
<?php
   $all = <<< STOPTHISCRAZYTHING
    <pre>
    echo "<br><br><textarea rows=\"30\" cols = \"100\">";
    echo "<div align=\"center\"><font size=\"7\">I Have</font></div>";
    foreach($same as $match)
        {
        echo "<img src=\"" . $match . "\">";
        }
    echo "<div align=\"center\"><font size=\"7\">I Need</font></div>";
    foreach($different as $diff)
        {
        if(!in_array($diff, $reject))
        {
        echo "<img src=\"" . $diff . "\">";
        }
        }
    echo "<div align=\"center\"><font size=\"7\">I Am Unable To Obtain</font></div>";
    foreach($retired_different as $unabletoget)
        {
        echo "<img src=\"" . $unabletoget . "\">";
        }
    echo "</textarea></pre>";
STOPTHISCRAZYTHING;

echo $all;

?>
```